# How to use Android ViewBinding for custom view which inflates from existing layout

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-viewbinding

I see there is ViewBinding support for Activity and Fragment. But how about custom view?

My custom view likes this:

```
class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
        defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this)
    }
}
```

I try to create ViewBinding but it doesn't work.

```
    private val binding: MyViewBinding

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this)
        binding = MyViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
    }
```

Do you have any solution for ViewBinding with custom view?

Answer (score 0):

you try replace

```
   init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this)
        binding = MyViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
    }
```

with

```
   init {
        binding = MyViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),this, false)
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `binding = MyViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),this, true)`? Otherwise view should be also added afterwards `addView(binding.root)`